# Best design practices with Android are different than Java?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

Let's imagine we only want to execute something if an preferences' option is set to true. It could be the class diagram of the situation:

[image: class diagram]

The implementation in **`PreferencesActivity`** of `getDoSomethingOptionValue()` could be as follows:

```
public boolean getDoSomethingOptionValue(){
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()
    return settings.getString("doSomethingOptionValue", "false");
}
```

---

**In Java** (I mean, no Android), **`MainActivity`** should use the get method from the `PreferencesActivity` to get the value:

```
if (PreferencesActivity.getDoSomethingOptionValue()){
    // TODO     
    executeSomething()
}
```

But it is actually **more complex to communicate activities with Android** (I like [this tutorial about how to communicate two running activities](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-running-activities)). **So I'm invited to check the preferences directly from `MainActivity`**. The code would be simpler and more efficent. It could be something like:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()
if (settings.getString("doSomethingOptionValue", "false"){
    // TODO     
    executeSomething()
}
```

**Which one is the recommended practice with Android?**

Comment: PreferencesActivity.getDoSomethingOptionValue() won't work as the method is not static

Comment: We solved this by using a PreferenceHandler that is responsible for all shared preferences and all set/get goes over it and can be accessed through the application so everywhere in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The principle of "don't repeat yourself" still applies, i.e. if you use the same code from two locations, factor it out into a common method. One example would be a static method in a `Settings` class:

   ```
   public class Settings {
       public static boolean getDoSomethingOptionValue(Context context) {
           SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
           return settings.getString("doSomethingOptionValue", "false");
       }
   }
   ```

   (Of course, more sophisticated options (non-static method, Settings object available via dependency injection) are possible, if your project requires it.)
2. You should not need to read the settings manually in your `PreferencesActivity`, [addPreferencesFromResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#addPreferencesFromResource%28int%29) can do that for you.

Comment: Where do you recommend to place the common method? Could it be an activity? (Taking into consideration that the method would do something without showing an interface to the user). Must it be a service? @for3st said something about handlers; I guess he is thinking in AsyncTask.

Comment: @chelder: I think a plain old Java class would be just fine.